# 0 Total Tests - 0 passed,0 failed ,0 skipped even after having tests in the class

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

While running unit test in Visual studio , i was getting 0 Total Tests - 0 passed,0 failed ,0 skipped even after having tests in the class.

Answer (score 9):

In Nunit, if there is an exception in loading test setup or execution it will result in above. From Visual studio menu open debug=>output and select Test window and see are there any exceptions thrown when tests are run. In my case in project1 i have nunit2 (refernce), in project2 i have nunit3 which referred project1 which is causing conflict and unable to execute.

if you resolve the exception it should work

Comment: In my case, the build configuration had the project un-selected for build

Answer (score 4):

Installing `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` package from nuget package manager solved my issue.
I also have `xunit` and `xunit.runner.visualstudio` package installed.

Comment: Similar solution here: I'm using xunit but was missing xunit.runner.visualstudio nuget package. I didn't need to use Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have runsettings file in your solution or if there is one selected under
VS -> Test -> Configure Run Settings. If this is chosen, uncheck it. Remove the file. This fixed for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure the access modifier of the class is `public` instead of `internal`.  If it is `internal` none of the `[Fact]`s in the class will register as tests within the Test Explorer, nor will they run.

Comment: By default the access modifier will be internal so we need to specifically decorate as public

Comment: This gets me every time for some reason. Maybe there should be a warning under classes annotated with [Test Class] when you don't specify public

Answer (score 2):

For MSTest users - if you have a method marked with the `[ClassInitialize]` attribute, make sure that it is both `public` and `static`, and has a single parameter of type `TestContext`, otherwise the test file will not run.

```cs
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{​​
    // initialization code...
}
```

Comment: Nice one.... Gave me the idea to check the attributes. In my case I had two [AssemblyInitialize] methods in two different classes. Thanks 

For anyone looking for additional info - Method denoted with [AssemblyInitialize] attribute runs once when the assembly is loaded, but [ClassInitialize] runs once before any test methods in the class and [TestInitialize] runs before each test method in the class.

Comment: That was the problem in my case, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here in my case the issue was different . In VS Unit tests are being identified based on Test class. In my case , there were no access modifier for the class and which caused the issue .VS unable to identify the test methods for the particular class.

```
 class ControllerTests
{    
    public Controller _Controller;
   
    [TestMethod()]
}
```

After adding public to the class ,it worked fine.
**Public** class ControllerTests
{
public Controller _Controller;

```
    [TestMethod()]
}
```

Comment: Great! In my case the issue was that the class was marked internal.

Answer (score 1):

In Case anyone is still struggling with this, installing "MSTest.TestAdapter" solved my issue.

Comment: This package along with MSTest.TestFramework were already showing as installed for me. I then right clicked the solution and selected Restore Nuget Packages. Then Build->Clean Solution. Then Build->Rebuild Solution. The other answers alone did not work for me. After this, tests worked again. No idea why they were working minutes early then just stopped.

Answer (score 1):

For me a simple "Clean Solution" worked.

Answer (score 1):

For C#/.NET Playwright:

I've seen this a couple times and my issue was that the return type of an async test method was void, instead of Task.  It should be as follows:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue trying to help a new developer on our team setup his development machine. The tests would show up in VS2022 TestExplorer, but running them would complete in a few ms, with the dreaded "0 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped" result. The Output|Tests window didn't show any errors.

After a "Clean Solution", the tests would run.

Answer (score 0):

On VS with Nunit, this Library does the trick:

NuGet\Install-Package NUnit3TestAdapter -Version 3.7.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After checking all the troubleshooting steps suggested by others here I closed VS2022 and reopened my solution. Then it began to work. Moral of the story is that there is a large number of root causes to this problem. Sometimes Visual Studio is just cursed and needs to be exorcised of deamons.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue while running tests on local machine on Visual studio, following solution fixed the issue,
Open Visual Studio, under Test -> Options, uncheck "Discover tests in real time from C# and Visual Basic .NET source files".
Restart Visual studio and if needed rebuild solution.